# can i return the GetBuilder in StatelessWidget build function directly?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

some days ago, i raise an issue which link https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/2038#issue-1075353819

now i think there are something wrong in use getx ?

in my project i always return GetBuilder in build function, because my Scaffold has too many logic and state to use.

like this

```dart
class AppLogsPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<AppLogsLogic>(builder: (l) => Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("app logs"),
      ),
      // ... many logic and state use
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

but i saw the official document many times, it show me place the GetBuilder in the area where has some logic or state should be inject.

so i want to know it will make me face some problem? or not the best practice in Getx

Comment: It will not cause you any problem besides performance. It's always a good practice to maintain local states.